# Custom validator attribute works in unit test but not the WebAPI controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, data-annotations

The ValidateMinMaxListCountAttribute validation attribute works in my unit test, but does not when used in WebAPI framework?

For example inside the unit test the "isValid" returns true, yet in the controller it fails. I'm guessing some kind of serialization issue?

Anyone have any ideas?

```
[TestCategory("ServiceTests")]
[TestMethod]
public void CallServiceCalc()
{

    var client = new RestClient();
    client.BaseUrl = new Uri("https://localhost:44379");
    client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("eric.schneider", "password");

    var request = new RestRequest();
    request.Resource = "api/Calculation/Calculate";

    CoralRequest coralReq = new CoralRequest();
    coralReq.ModelId = 1;
    coralReq.ModelName = "2018";
    coralReq.BasePlan = new BeneifitsPlanInputs();
    coralReq.Plans.Add(new BeneifitsPlanInputs());
    request.AddBody(coralReq);

    ValidateMinMaxListCountAttribute va = new ValidateMinMaxListCountAttribute(1, 999);
    bool isValid = va.IsValid(coralReq.Plans);

    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

    Assert.IsTrue(response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, "Should not be ok");
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ValidateMinMaxListCountAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public ValidateMinMaxListCountAttribute(int minimum, int maximum)

{
    this.MinimumCount = minimum;
    this.MaximumCount = maximum;
}

public int MinimumCount { get; set; }
public int MaximumCount { get; set; }

public override bool IsValid(object value)
{
    var list = value as ICollection;

    if (list != null)
    {
        if (list.Count > MaximumCount) { return false; }
        if (list.Count < MinimumCount) { return false; }
        return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}


   public class CoralRequest
    {
        public CoralRequest()

    {
        this.Plans = new List<BeneifitsPlanInputs>();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    [ValidateMinMaxListCount(1, 99, ErrorMessage = "Must have between 1 and 99 plans")]
    public IList<BeneifitsPlanInputs> Plans { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work in web api framework"?

Comment: My controller class validates and says it's a bad request, with the validation error of the attribute.

Comment: For `a bad request`, it does not happen to validate the model. If you put a breakpoint on `ValidateMinMaxListCountAttribute`, will it be hit when calling from web api? Share us your client request.

Comment: I did share it; I'm call the service from the unit test. As I said in the unit test I added a test call of ValidateMinMaxListCountAttribute , and it works, and can debug. But the mvc framework call does not

Comment: Tao, it mus be validating because I get the validation error message "Must have between 1 and 99 plans", yet I do have a plan in there...

Comment: #Nkosi, I was expecting if to pass validation, but was receiving a failed message, indicating that the validation was performed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on one of your other questions, which seems to be related, you show that the controller action looks like...

```
[HttpGet("{mock}")]
public ActionResult<CoralResult> CalculateMock(CoralRequest mock)
```

While in the test, a GET request is being made, GET requests do not have a BODY, and yet you add one to the request. Meaning that most likely the model is not being populated/bind to correctly on the server

This looks like a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

That action should most likely be a POST request if you want to get the BODY of the request, and the action should be refactored to explicitly state where the data should be attained from.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class CalculationController: Controller {

    //POST api/Calculation/Calculate
    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public ActionResult<CoralResult> Calculate([FromBody]CoralRequest model) {
        if(ModelState.IsValid) {
            CoralResult result = new CoralResult();

            //...do something with model and populate result.

            return result;
        }
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

}
```

Which should now match more closely to what was being attempted in the integration test

```
[TestCategory("ServiceTests")]
[TestMethod]
public void CallServiceCalc() {

    var client = new RestClient();
    client.BaseUrl = new Uri("https://localhost:44379");
    client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("eric.schneider", "password");

    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST); //<-- POST request
    request.Resource = "api/Calculation/Calculate";
    request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");

    CoralRequest coralReq = new CoralRequest();
    coralReq.ModelId = 1;
    coralReq.ModelName = "2018";
    coralReq.BasePlan = new BeneifitsPlanInputs();
    coralReq.Plans.Add(new BeneifitsPlanInputs());
    request.AddJsonBody(coralReq); //<-- adding data as JSON to body of request

    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

    Assert.IsTrue(response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, "Should be HttpStatusCode.OK");
}
```

The model binder should now be able to validate the model after binding it and passing it to the action.

Reference [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1)